# is it possible having different Kodi version accessing the same MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, database, kodi

I'm trying to have Kodi installed on several machine but accessing one single database MySQL. 
at some machine it just cannot install the latest Kodi version.
so when all setup, the oldest Kodi version cannot find the (correct) database.
is there any setting or tweak for such condition?
thanks

Comment: You have to be more precise about your actions and observations. Any error messages?

Comment: You will need to use the same version on all kodi instances.